# Need help installing the ulsy package in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, ubuntu

I'm trying to install ulsy in order to use its blitz symbols for proofs by contradiction.  I downloaded the metafont source from CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ulsy?lang=en

I then unzipped it in `texmf/tex/latex`

I ran `latex ulsy.ins` and `latex ulsy.dtx` and produced the .sty file.

At this point, the compiler was able to find the .sty file but produced an error message saying that it could not find the .tfm file.  Somme other answers suggested that this problem could be resolved by installing the following:

`texlive-latex-recommended`

`texlive-latex-extra`

`texlive-fonts-recommended`

However, this did not work for me.

I then tried moving the .tfm file to `texmf/fonts/tfm/public/ulsy` and the .mf file to `texmf/fonts/source/ulsy`

Now when I try to use the symbols in math mode, I just get arbitrary greek letters, but my understanding is that ulsy's symbols are supposed to be used in text mode anyway.

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error message when I try to use ulsy's symbols in text mode:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ulsy10): Font ulsy10 at 600 not found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>
> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ulsy10
>
> mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ulsy10.
>
> mktexpk: perhaps ulsy10 is missing from the map file.
>
> kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>
> Execution halted

Can anyone point me in the right direction or guide me through the manual installation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.